# Error output in nextflow pipeline using fasterq-dump

Tags: nextflow, fastq-dump

I have one file with multiple SRA accession called `Dataframe_with_accession.txt`, for this example I just put one SRA in that file called :`SRR8933535`

And the idea is to create a nextflow pipeline to download the sra files in the `Dataframe_with_accession.txt`, zip the files  using `pigz` and remove the previous `fastq file`

To do that I used this code :

```
params.inputFile = "/crex/proj/Dataframe_with_accession.txt"
params.outputDir = "/crex/proj/Output"


process DOWNLOAD_FASTQ {

    publishDir params.outputDir, mode: 'symlink'

    input:
    each (accession)

    output:
    tuple path("params.outputDir/${accession}_1.fastq.gz")
    path("params.outputDir/${accession}_2.fastq.gz")

    script:
    """
    fasterq-dump --threads 12 --outdir ${params.outputDir}  ${accession}
    pigz -p12 ${params.outputDir}/${accession}_1.fastq
    pigz -p12 ${params.outputDir}/${accession}_2.fastq
    """
}

workflow {
    // Read accessions from the input file
    accList = file(params.inputFile).readLines()

    DOWNLOAD_FASTQ(accList)
}
```

Then I run this nextflow file.

But I got the following error message :

```
[01/298f4b] process > DOWNLOAD_FASTQ (1) [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✘
Error executing process > 'DOWNLOAD_FASTQ (1)'

Caused by:
  Missing output file(s) `SRR8933535_1.fastq` expected by process `DOWNLOAD_FASTQ (1)`

Command executed:

  fasterq-dump --threads 12 --outdir /crex/proj/Output  SRR8933535

Command exit status:
  0

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  spots read      : 8,389,148
  reads read      : 16,778,296
  reads written   : 16,778,296

Work dir:
  /crex/proj/Output/work/01/298f4be6dde2ee1856df31db169bec

Tip: you can try to figure out what's wrong by changing to the process work dir and showing the script file named `.command.sh`
```

And I do not undestrand what is going wrong here ? It says

```
Command output:
  (empty)
```

But the file is created

Comment: Are you aware of the fromSRA Nextflow channel factory? https://www.nextflow.io/docs/edge/channel.html#fromsra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each nextflow process looks in its working directory for the files listed in `output:` . In your `script:` you already direct the output to its eventual destination. After running the script nextflow tries to find the output files and stops, because it can't find them. Solution: keep the output files in your workdir, nextflow will detect them and use the `publishDir` directive to copy  them to their eventual destination.

Comment: ok perfect thanks